# JWT authorization works only in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, interceptor

- Ruby version: 2.2.4
- Rails version: 5.0.0.1

I am just a beginner in programming and I have the task to create an android app with Android Studio, where you can login and logout as a user and which uses a ruby on rails server.

I followed a token-based authentication tutorial with Ruby on Rails 5 API (http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api). This tutorial shows how I get a token with JWT. After putting the right credentials in curl I finally receive a token.

When I open the console and use the token in curl like this..

```
curl -H "Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJleHAiOjE0NjA2NTgxODZ9.xsSwcPC22IR71OBv6bU_OGCSyfE89DvEzWfDU0iybMA" http://localhost:3000/items
```

..I finally can receive Information from the authorized area http://localhost:3000/items in the console. But if I open http://localhost:3000/items in the webbrowser I still get an error, that the user is not authorized.

So how can I implement, that the user can go into the authorized area in web browser after he logged in from the android app? I really dont know how to do this, but I heard an interceptor could do this. How can I exactly implement this into the code? Or are there other solutions?

Comment: It's not going to work in the browser because the browser is not sending along the Authorization header. The browser doesn't know anything about that. With curl, you've specified Authorization header with your token, so that's why it works. The point of your API will be to return data to your Android app, so your Android app will need to make a request to the API with the token in the Authorization header of the request, similar to how you've done it with curl.

Comment: so how can I implement that the browser is sending along the Authorization header?

Comment: You would make an AJAX request with javascript, but this leads to a much broader topic: are you writing a javascript app? are you using jquery or some other library? I thought you were making an android app? My guess is you're making an android app but would like to test your API outside of the app. In that case, skip the browser and use something like Postman which is a GUI for making http requests and allows you to specify headers.

Comment: I make a android app which uses a ruby on rails server. I need to login and logout from my android app to this server and send camera-photo to this RoR server for the authorized user. Do you know how to send pictures? Can I do that with JWT ? Probably not..

Comment: Think of JWT as just a piece of authentication that you send along with your HTTP requests. You'll need an endpoint on your Rails app that you can POST file uploads to. Then you need to make an HTTP POST request from your android app, probably using "multipart form data", to send the picture, along with a JWT authorization header. I suggest you take it one step at a time. You can find stack overflow answers on how to do the various steps.